# Why is my Haskell function argument required to be of type Bool?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference

I have a function in Haskell that is defined as follows:

```
f2 x y = if x then x else y
```

When trying to determine the type of `y`, I would assume it could be of any valid Haskell type, since it is not required for evaluating the if-part. However, checking the type signature with

```
:type f2
```

yields

```
f2 :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
```

Why does the `y` argument need to be of type `Bool` in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haskell values have types. Each value has a type. One type. It can't be two different types at the same time.

Thus, since `x` is returned as the result of `if`'s consequent, the type of the whole `if ... then ... else ...` expression is the same as `x`'s type.

An `if` expression has a type. Thus both its consequent and alternative expression must have that same type, since either of them can be returned, depending on the value of the test. Thus both must have the same type.

Since `x` is also used in the test, it must be `Bool`. Then so must be `y`.

Comment: "It can't be two different types at the same time."

It can be one type or the other, though, if you use a sum type like an Either.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt then it's one type, the sum type. I guess what you're saying is, `y` could have different type if the code was changed to `if x then (Right x) else (Left y)`.